# How to postpone an update to a Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Is there an easy way to tell a Two-way WPF data binding to wait a few milliseconds after the last change before updating the Source with the new property value?

I'm implementing a filter feature for a ListBox where I have a textbox, and I want to filter the content of the ListBox according to what I type. I'm using data binding to connect the pieces together. Filtering the list can be quite time consuming, so I don't want to do it after every character that is typed: hence my request.

I have been using Paul Stovell's DelayBinding Extension (his site's down at the moment, so I can't link to it). However, I suspect that it is the cause of a memory leak in my applicataion (caused by it not removing event handlers).

Does anybody else have any other ideas?

Comment: Just confirming, I experienced similar problem with DelayBinding. I had a MVVM shell application which housed a StackPanel full of Menu buttons and a main ContentControl. The ContentControl.Content was set by a property on the Shell ViewModel, however If I loaded a UserControl which included a DelayBinding, and then switched the Content, memory usage just went through the roof. Memory Profiler confirmed that the old Content UserControls were prevented from being collected by the GC.

Answer (score 18):

I'm also a few years late, but if you're using WPF 4.5+ [there is now an property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay.aspx) exactly for this purpose, it's called `Delay`.

Description

> The amount of time, in milliseconds, to wait before updating the
>   binding source.

Example usage

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Delay=500}"/>
```

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the question here (just a few years :) but for anyone who's interested I had a similar requirement in a project so I created two markup extensions called `DelayBindingExtension` and `DelayMultiBindingExtension`.

They work like normal `Bindings` with the addition that you can specify `UpdateSourceDelay` and/or `UpdateTargetDelay`, both of which are `TimeSpan` properties. Also, I've verified that it's leak-free *(it makes use of the propertychanged callback of a dependency property binding through inheritance context rather than the `DependencyPropertyDescriptor`)*.

Example usage for a `DelayBinding`

```
<TextBox Text="{db:DelayBinding Path=TextProperty,
                                UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                UpdateSourceDelay='00:00:01'}"/>
```

And for a `DelayMultiBinding`

```
<cs:ColorSelector.SelectedColor>
    <db:DelayMultiBinding Mode="TwoWay"
                          Converter="{StaticResource ColorConverter}"
                          UpdateSourceDelay="00:00:02"
                          UpdateTargetDelay="00:00:01">
        <Binding Path="Red" />
        <Binding Path="Green" />
        <Binding Path="Blue" />
    </db:DelayMultiBinding>
</cs:ColorSelector.SelectedColor>
```

Source code and sample usage for `DelayBinding` and `DelayMultiBinding` can be downloaded [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qb88bg4jjibbnru/DelayBindingDemo.zip?dl=0).
If you're interested in the implementation details, you can check out my blog post about it here: [DelayBinding and DelayMultiBinding with Source and Target delay](http://meleak.wordpress.com/2012/05/02/delaybinding-and-delaymultibinding-with-source-and-target-delay/)

Comment: I'm aware this is an old answer, but if you're using .Net Framework 4.5, there is [a delay property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.delay.aspx)

Comment: Looks like everyone's late here, but thank you for this, its usage is perfect. My question being: it looks quite heavy, doesn't it impact performance too much?

Comment: @Kilazur: I haven't looked at the implementation of this in a while but it shouldn't have a notable impact on performance. I'm using it in almost every project and I've never noticed any decrease in performance anyway :-)

Comment: One limitation of this solution is that the property cannot be changed quickly and continuously. In this case, the binding will not work because the internal timer will stop before the new value is set to the target.

Answer (score 2):

First, to answer your question, I would add the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) binding extension which will let you control when the binding updates. Try LostFocus first but it sounds like you might want to go for Explicit.

Second, if your filtering takes a long time I would look into using CollectionViewSource on your ListBox. Bea Stollnitz has a good primer on it [here](http://www.beacosta.com/blog/?p=17) and I used [this blog post](http://sandyvalley.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!AB1484B25F28E501!461.entry) to show me how to filter. When I changed over I noticed a huge speed difference over my other implementation even though they use the same filtering functions. Also CollectionViewSource will automatically handle updating filtered items if the list you're bound to changes, even on the item level if you're binding to an ObservableCollection (this is the original reason I changed to CollectionViewSource).

HTH

Comment: Thanks Bryan. I was aware of UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit but I was hoping somebody would have a ready made solution (along the lines of DelayBinding) that would take care of triggering the update after a delay.